# Ocultar/deshabilitar valores seleccionados de un combobox (combobox cargado desde una base de datos)

Tags: javascript, html, python, sql

cordial saludo. Alguien me puede ayuda por favor con ideas para lo siguiente: Tengo que llenar un combo con unos horarios de atención de lapsos de 10 minutos, p.e: 07:00 am, 07:10 am ... hasta llegar a 07:00 pm, y también tengo un textbox con tiempo estimado de atención (porque el tiempo de atención es cambiante). Si escojo la hora(inicial) de atención 07:00 am y tiempo estimado de atención 20 minutos, una vez guardo, el combobox ya no debe mostrar los horarios 07:00 am, 07:10, sólo mostrar de las 07:20 en adelante. Lo que he pensado es crea una tabla con todos los horarios de atención, pero no se como ocultar los rango que se escojan. Es como un consultorio de citas, sólo que los horarios son estimados. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. Aquí no se dan orientaciones: muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido.

Comment: 2 preguntas: Javascript o python???? sí colocas tiempo estimado 30min, la secuencia es 7.30,8.00,8.30,etc ???? Es decir el tiempo estimado afecta para todas la horas, o solo afecta a una??

Comment: Hola @Yussef, gracias por responder. 1. Resp. La aplicación está en Python-Flask, en el front lo tengo con html, css y Javascript.  2. Resp. Si por ejemplo escojo en el combo las 07:00 am y tiempo estimado 30 min. Después de guardar, el combo ya no debe mostrar 07:00, 07:10, 07:20, pero sí debe mostrar disponible 07:30, 07:40 ... etc., porque los primero 30 minutos ya estarían reservados. Espero haberme explicado bien.